# PHP complex multidimensional array iteration

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need to iterate through multidimensional array. But I need to do it complex: iteration must go by levels - at first elements of 1 level, only after them elements of 2 level, after them elements of 3 level, etc.

I can write it myself if I want to, but I need to make sure I'm not reinventing the wheel. Is there any ready implementation of this in PHP?

**UPDATE**

What code should i provide? It's a theoretical issue. I can provide you an array.. :

```
Array
(
    [lev1_1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3547
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [lev2_1] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 3550
                        )

                    [lev2_2] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 3551
                        )
                )
        )
    [lev1_2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 3547
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [lev2_3] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 3550
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [lev3_1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 3550
                                        )

                                    [lev3_2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 3551
                                        )
                                )
                        )

                    [lev2_4] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 3551
                        )
                )
        )
```

I need iterate through lev1_x, then lev2_x, then lev3_x

Comment: Is there any code you gonna show to us ?

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: To further emphasize. **Please show us some code**.

Comment: It is theoretical question. But i've posted update for you.

Comment: You need to provide the code you have tried so far to iterate through the array! we're not going to do your work for you! Unless you plan to pay that is.

Comment: Usual code iterates from parent to last child. No matter what is inside this algorythm. I need another algorythm of iteration.

Comment: This type of traversal is commonly referred to as [breadth-first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Breadth-first).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's a dumb way to get the values by level. Please note that you'll need to tweak the code according to your use.

```
function array_values_by_level($array, $level = 0, &$values = null) {
    if ($values === null)
        $values = array();
    if (!isset($values[$level]))
        $values[$level] = array();
    foreach ($array as $v) {
        if (is_array($v))
            array_values_by_level($v, $level + 1, &$values);
        else
            $values[$level][] = $v;
    }

    return $values;
}
```

Test case:

```
$big_array = array(
    '1',
    '2',
    array(
        '2.1',
        '2.2',
        array(
            '2.2.1',
            '2.2.2',
            array(
                '2.2.2.1'
            )
        ),
        '2.3',
        array(
            '2.3.1',
            array(
                '2.3.1.1',
                '2.3.1.2'
            )
        )
    )
);

foreach (array_values_by_level($big_array) as $k => $v)
    printf("[%d] %s \n", $k, implode(', ', $v));

// [0] 1, 2
// [1] 2.1, 2.2, 2.3
// [2] 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.1
// [3] 2.2.2.1, 2.3.1.1, 2.3.1.2
```